# How to post data from VueJS with PHP?

Tags: php, post, vue.js

Please Help me, How to post data using the request which made by Vue.js

There's `Vue`'s code

```
let tests = {
    cat1: {
        name: 'Auth',
        items: {
            authorize2: {
                name: 'Successful',
                subname: '',
                request: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    link: 'auth',
                    data: {
                        login: 'admin',
                        password: 'password'
                    }
                },
                test: (result, status) => {
                    if (status.status == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }}}}
```

PHP page which receives this code doesn't have anything in POST data storage.

Comment: could you show all the code that contains this snippet?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim sure, just added!

Comment: so i understand tht ht given code is inside a method? are you using vue cli 3 or just CDN?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim it's not inside a method. I use just vue.js straight from file on my PC

Comment: so you could use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios) to post your data

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim oh, but why my code doesn't work? It should, right?

Comment: i need more details like the `url` to your php api and this code is inside what in order to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally Vue used the [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) package to perform POST requests via the $http instance property:

```
login(){
    var data = {
      login: 'admin',
      password: 'password'
    }
    this.$http.post('/auth', data)
        .then(response => { /* success callback */ }, response => { /* error callback */ })
}
```

In Vue2 [vue-resource was retired](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4) and they started to recommend [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). They also offered a way to [override the $http instance property](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Real-World-Example-Replacing-Vue-Resource-with-Axios) allowing you to invoke the axios library in a similar way.

```
this.$http.post('/auth', data)
    .then(response => { /* success callback */ })
    .catch(error => { /* error callback */ })
```

Or you can just load the Axios Package and call it directly:

```
const axios = require('axios');

...

axios.post('/auth', data)
    .then(response => { /* success callback */ })
    .catch(error => { /* error callback */ })
```

You could even choose to use vanilla js or another library like jQuery and use $.ajax() to make the request within your Vue instance, but [using axios](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html) is the current recommendation from Vue.